# Memory management with UITableViewCells from a NIB?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Usually when I setup a `UITableViewCell` I used the default cellStyles, allocating and autoreleasing the cells as needed. My question is with regards to the memory management in the example below. Where is the `FGCustomCell` allocated, is it created when I ask for the objects includde in the nib? I am also assuming its autoreleased so the code below is fine?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    FGCustomCell *customCell = (FGCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FGCELL_ID"];
    if(customCell == nil) {
        NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FGCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for(id eachObject in nibObjects) {
            if([eachObject isKindOfClass:[FGCustomCell class]]) customCell = (FGCustomCell *)eachObject;
        }
    }
    return customCell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the FGCustomCell is allocated by the loading of the nib and is created autoreleased.